# select query join with the first row based on condition

Tags: postgresql

I work with postgresql.

I have a table named callnum which have 4 columns :id,tag position,tag,catalog_id.

and each catalog is related to one row of callnum but some time one row catalog is related to more than one row of callnum with the same tag_number

in this case I want to get the data from the first row of callnum based on min of tag_position

but the problem in this case that the query became very slow.

this query is very fast :

```
select distinct(item.id) as id,item.id_item as idItem,item.date_created as dateCreated ,callnum700.tag
     from item item 
     inner join catalog catalog on catalog.id=item.catalog_id 
     left outer join callnum callnum700 on callnum700.catalog_id=catalog.id and callnum700.tag_number='700'  
    
order by dateCreated desc 

limit 10 offset 0
```

but with this query it is very slow :

```
select distinct(item.id) as id,item.id_item as idItem,item.date_created as dateCreated ,callnum700.tag
     from item item 
     inner join catalog catalog on catalog.id=item.catalog_id 
     left outer join callnum callnum700 on callnum700.catalog_id=catalog.id and callnum700.tag_number='700'   
    and callnum700.tag_position = (select min(tag_position) from callnum callnum where callnum.catalog_id=catalog.id and callnum.tag_number='700')  
    
order by dateCreated desc 

limit 10 offset 0
```

can someone help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `inner join` could be faster than a subquery :

```
select distinct(item.id) as id,item.id_item as idItem,item.date_created as dateCreated ,callnum700.tag
from item 
inner join catalog on catalog.id=item.catalog_id 
left outer join callnum callnum700 on callnum700.catalog_id=catalog.id
inner join (
  select min(tag_position) as min_tag_position
  from callnum
  inner join catalog on callnum.catalog_id=catalog.id
  where callnum.tag_number='700'
) s on s.min_tag_position = callnum700.tag_position
and callnum700.tag_number='700'   
order by dateCreated desc;
```

Also you will have to add some multi-column indexes :

```
ON callnum(catalog_id, tag_number, tag_position)
ON item(catalog_id, dateCreated)
```

Comment: thank you for your response , I have an error where running your query  :      ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "catalog"
LINE 12:   where callnum.catalog_id=catalog.id and callnum.tag_number='700'
                                 ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "catalog", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: I have made an update, Can you recheck